# What should I choose - GPU Mining or CPU Mining?

Tags: gpu-mining, cpu-mining

I have a HP Pavilion G6-2313AX Laptop with 
Processor  : APU Quad Core A10 and
Graphics  : 512 MB AMD Radeon HD 7660G (Integrated) and 2 GB ATI Mobility Radeon 7670M HD Graphics (Dedicated)

I know both specifications are not enough for dedicated mining. But I'm interested in it and just want to try mining.

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

It is likely that neither is profitable for you, because ASIC miners are alot more effective than any GPU mining, which in turn is alot faster than CPU mining. But don't take my word for it. [This hardware comparison wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_Hardware_Comparison) is a good source to make an initial estimate. There is one entry listing the combination of an A10 and a HD7660G GPU, claiming to get 105 MHash/s just from the graphics card (and not listing any value for the CPU).

If that doesn't deter you---at 100 MHash/s you are looking at an expected average reward of less than a dollar per month, probably less than the electricity your computer needs is worth---please consider updating that wiki with the performance you are getting.

Answer (score 5):

CPU mining is **DEAD**. GPU mining is **DEAD**. Even  **FPGA mining is DEAD** !

ASIC's ? 
Yes them still can be profitable. But..... ONLY if you can get your ASIC  cheap.
Here are the maximum prices you can pay for ASIC, and still have some hopes to get ROI in 3-4 month:

- 40+ GHs for 1BTC - if you get your machine TODAY
- 75+ GH/BTC - if ASIC delivered within 1 month
- 160+ GH/BTC - if ASIC delivered within 2 month

Why ROI in 3-4 month?
Because if it takes longer, most likelly you will never get your money back
Never forget this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GERC.png
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin mining with either CPU or GPU looses money on account of the amount you spend on power is greater then your expected returns. GPU mining is still profitable for mining some alt-coins such as [litecoin](https://litecoin.org/) but likewise CPU mining losses money in these instances as well.

So if your interested in getting started mining, I would recommend GPU mining either feather coin or litecoin. Anything else will likely loose you money.

Answer (score 1):

CPU mining is just a novelty, but you can start there. But beware: if you are using a laptop, you risk damaging it with excessive heat.

GPU mining is faster but to be successful you'll need a high-end graphics card in a desktop computer and those cards are $1000.

And even then, GPU mining is rather inefficient compared to desktop ASIC boxes.